# How write platform driver in linux

Tags: linux, driver, low-level-code

I started to write linux driver and i am confident on it now, but my interest now is to write
lower-level driver (platform driver) for spi or USB or i2c controller. Is there any i can start writing to practice platform driver on linux PC.  Can some suggest how to start writing platform driver on linux.

Thank you

Comment: So you want to write generic functions other drivers can use to communicate with their own hardware? The way you write the code is still the same, you write a kernel module! By the way, the kernel already has an API for SPI, I2C etc. Have you taken a look at them?

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to look at the existing drivers, look at the list of open bugs and start to fix them. That will give you a good introduction to the kernel, you will learn to work as part of a huge, distributed team (will look good on your CV) and you will help to make the world better, one line of code at a time.

The next step is then to find some unknown, unsupported hardware and write a driver for it. The start here is to copy an existing driver or extend it (depending on how "different" the hardware is).